# Is there a reliable trustworthy way to do a digital signature in c#?

Tags: c#, database, security

I have written in the past sites with "I agree" types of terms and conditions. This response is stored against the user in the DB.

But it dawned on me that if there was some sort of dispute over this, i wouldn't be able to prove that I hadn't fabricated this agreement from the user.

How do people deal with these situations, how can you set up an actual proof of agreement that will prove at the least that someone with the users credentials has "agreed"?

-- Initial thoughts turn to cryptography, but i cant think how to utilise this.

Comment: This a really a security question. From where will the users credentials come? How will you authenticate? Asking some prearranged security question seems to be common.

Comment: I would say this is more a legal question. A consultation with a lawyer that is a digital signing expert is due.

Comment: Put a tick box on it saying "Tick here if you're just pretending to be someone else", or maybe some microsoft style "Are you sure" popups

Comment: @Jodrell Dont think it matters, lets just say the system believes "Joe Blogs" is logged in and has clicked "I agree". For the sake of this question i'd like to ignore that the users account / password may have been compromised.

Comment: @Kohan but, that is the root of problem, no? Introducing an independent "more trusted" (and expensive) third party, to handle the sigining process, might help.

Comment: @Jodrell: No. The problem the OP is facing is much simpler: The user actually clicked that he agreed but in a legal dispute the OP can't proof it.

Comment: @Jodrell my problem is, assuming you know 100% that someone has clicked "I Agree" on a form / webpage. How can i record this agreement  and still prove that i have not fabricated this response by adding a record to the database myself.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, so, this really isn't a programming question.

Comment: @Jodrell: Indeed. That's why I upvoted Odeds comment.

Comment: I electronically sign contracts on a fairly regular basis. The company I'm contracting to offloads the signing to a larger organisation to independently verify the signing. A copy of those contract remain on the Third Party site for us all to look at.

Comment: @Jodrell I figured the solution could be achieved using cryptography, but couldnt think how. I also wondered if this was a common situation with a standard method of dealing with it using code.

Comment: @Kohan, cryptography is used but who holds the private key that locks the signed document/certificate. Thats where independent third party comes in. You'd have to consult a legal expert to see how binding these actual arrangements are.

Comment: Kohan poses an interesting question. How can one prove that the "UserAgreed" column in the database has a value of "true" because the user clicked some button and not because the dba ran an update query?

I'm no expert but I assume that it would involve requiring all users of your site to get a digital certificate for themselves (with a private key that you don't have access to). You could then generate a randomstring, ask the client to encode it with their personal private key, and store both the randomstring and encoded in your DB.

Comment: @Jodrell Maybe add an answer saying this can be done with a trustworthy 3rd party, but i cant think what they would do to ensure authenticity either... they are in the same boat, what if i bribed them to fabricate a response?

Comment: @Kohan: "trustworthy" in this context implies that you can't bribe them. That means you will have to use a large company which not only you think of as trustworthy but that it is generally seen as trustworthy.